# How to know the keys of post in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, post

I went through this tutorial: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/13/tutorial-create-admin-manageable-magento-entity-brands/.

When accessing the post data, the author uses:

```
 $this->getRequest()->getPost('brandData')
```

I am wondering how can we know there is a brandData key in the post data?

---

NOTE: I know I can see the available keys using the

```
var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost())
```

But I want to know how to know it without manually print the whole post data.

Comment: We can use array_key_exists function to check the particular key is exist in array or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available fields all yield from html form elements whose values have been sent to the controller that then works with the post data.

So there probably is a code snippet similar to this one

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/your/controllerAction">
    <input type="text" name="brandData" value="Default value" />
</form>
```

on the page used to send data to your controller.

Comment: I checked the form, but the input tag is like: <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="bzXFC2rh1vO0FAbY">

Comment: There's probably not only one input element in the form. You should probably check out [How HTML forms work](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) if you are not yet familiar with that.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, there are many input elements in the form, e.g., brandData[name], brandData[url]. It seems that Magento automatically turn them into an array. Are they each one corresponds to a post value?

Comment: You're right, if the name of the input field contains braces it is considered an array.

That means if a form contains following input (or select,textarea, ...) elements  

`<input name="brandData[name]" value="This is my name" />
<input name="brandData[url]" value="http://niceurl.com" />`  

then  

`$this->getRequest()->getPost('brandData')` will yield the following array:  

`array('name' => 'This is my name',  
          'url' => 'http://niceurl.com');`